# xcodebuild from command line - entitlement issues -SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, codesign, entitlements

I have two applications - one has a space in the name, the other doesn't.  when I try to run the application through my command line build process I have problems with the application being able to function properly - ie: bombs out with "SecItemCopyMatching: missing entitlement"

--- When I attempt to check the entitlements on the command line of the application with the space:

```
>machine:Release-iphoneos builder$ codesign -d --entitlements - Application\ Name.app 
Executable=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/My_Application_Name/workspace/build/Release-iphoneos/Application Name.app/Application Name
```

--- When I run this on an app without the space in the name:

```
machine:Release-iphoneos builder$ codesign -d --entitlements - application.app         
Executable=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/My_Application_Name/workspace/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/Application.app/Application
??qq?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>ABC123456.com.company.app</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>ABC123456.com.company.app</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

So the big question here is - this application name is already being used globally and I can't change it - how can I fix this issue so that I can do these command line builds???

IMNHO: Apple has made a big mistake in it's non-posix compliance in xcode.

Any suggestions appreciated.

APPLE'S RESPONSE:  "The Code Signing of iOS applications is only supported by DTS when using the Xcode app to build and sign your applications.  Their isn't a supported workflow for signing iOS Applications using xcodebuild."

So they don't support their own command line tools...

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using and do you have the latest version of the command line tools?  I just setup a test app with a space in the name 'Test App.app' and was able to run the entitlements check you were having issues with.  I'm on Xcode 4.6.2 with up-to-date command line tools here.

Comment: It works now.  Over night with no real modification on my part, possibly removing and re-pulling my provisioning profiles did it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that removing all provisioning profiles solved this, although I did that on a few occasions prior to the last time I did it with no luck.  It resolved itself one night on an automated build much to my surprise...